Django Allauth: Keycloak Authentication Fails with "Connection Refused" Error
Django Allauth: Keycloak Authentication Fails with "Connection Refused" Error
`I'm integrating Keycloak with my Django application using django-allauth for OpenID Connect authentication. I've set up the configuration, but when I click on the "Login with Keycloak" link, I encounter the following error:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: /realms/customercloud/.well-known/openid-configuration (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8d322fb100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
/**login.html **/
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'openid_connect' %}">Login with Keycloak</a>
`SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
"openid_connect": {
"APP": {
"provider_id": "keycloak",
"name": "Keycloak",
"client_id": "myclient",
"secret": "********************",
"settings": {
'server_url': 'http://localhost:/realms/customercloud/.well-known/openid-configuration',
'client_id': 'myclient',
'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:***/',
},
}
}
}
`
'

Are both of the Django and Keycloak running directly on your localhost machine, or are both or either one of them is running inside containers running on your localhost machine or somewhere else? "localhost" can only be used to refer to another service (e.g. Keycloak) running exactly in the same localhost machine or the same container as the application (e.g. Django) that wants to connect to it.
